# 'TypeError: an integer is required' when initializing random weight matrix in numpy with numpy.random.randn()

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, initialization, neural-network

So I am using numpy to build a neural net from matrices, and I have the following code for initialization:

```
for i in xrange(self.num_layers-1):
    self.params['W%d' % i] = np.random.randn(input_dim, hidden_dims) * weight_scale
    self.params['b%d' % i] = np.zeros(hidden_dims)
```

All variables are predefined;

```
type(input_dim) == integer
type(hidden_dims) == integer
type(self.num_layers) == integer
weight_scale == 1e-3
```

However, when I deploy this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 201, in __init__
self.params['W%d' % i] = np.random.randn(input_dim, hidden_dims) * weight_scale
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1680, in mtrand.RandomState.randn (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:17783)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1810, in mtrand.RandomState.standard_normal (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:18250)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 163, in mtrand.cont0_array (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:2196)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I have tried searching for this error but cannot get any relevant matches. Any idea what could have gone wrong? I have also tried using np.random.normal(scale=weigh_tscale, size=(input_dim, hidden_dims)) and I have received the same

```
'TypeError: an integer is required'
```

Thank you in advance for any clues!

---

Update: This was using python2, not 3

Comment: Please read the docstring again: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html.  Each argument `d0`, `d1`, etc, must be an integer (not a sequence of integers).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser oops, sorry, there was a typo; those are actually not sequences of integers but (single) integers; i will double check my code if there is something wrong with the input, but is there anything else that comes to your mind as a cause for this problem? Oh and thank you very much for the swift answer!

Comment: What is the output if you add this line just before the call to `randn`: `print(type(input_dim), input_dim, type(hidden_dims), hidden_dims)`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thank you very much! I double checked the input and it seemed like there was a special case where the input was a unhandled list... thank you so much!!

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser you can also mark your comment as an answer if anyone should happen to do this mistake aswell... there were no relevant search-hits, and i could mark your answer if 'answered' if you like aswell :) and thanks again!

Comment: I just made a few suggestions; you solved the problem.  You could answer the question yourself.  Or, since the problem was just a mistake in your code, you could delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled `range` to `xrange`. This will solve your problem.

```
for i in range(self.num_layers-1):
    self.params['W%d' % i] = np.random.randn(input_dim, hidden_dims) * weight_scale
    self.params['b%d' % i] = np.zeros(hidden_dims)
```

Otherwise, `np.random.randn(input_dim, hidden_dims)` should not be the metrics size in double braces like `np.random.randn((input_dim, hidden_dims))`

Comment: This was using python 2, so not a typo. Thanks tho!